# Is there an intuition behind the formula of chi-square?

Tags: chi-squared-test, intuition

Why in this formula $\chi^2 = \sum_i \frac{(x_i - m_i)^2}{m_i}$, we divide by $m_i$ instead of $m_i^2$? Dividing by the squared value has a clear logic for me that we are comparing the difference against the mean, in terms of ratio (I am not saying that it is correct :), but dividing by the means themselves is not. Are we doing some kind of normalization here, like variance per unit of mean value?

Comment: I think a version of this question has been answered before. I'll see if I can locate one.

Comment: Note that for the Poisson distribution, variance=mean, and because of the relationship between the multinomial and the Poisson (specifically in this case, the Poisson becomes the multinomial when conditioning on the total count), this extends to the multinomial (you're no longer dividing by variance, but it exactly accounts for the dependence induced by that conditioning)

Comment: You are correct: this is the *standardization* of the $x_i-m_i$ terms.  However, the variance is (approximately) $m_i$ and therefore the correct standardization should look (asymptotically) like $(x_i-m_i)/\sqrt{m_i}.$ Thus, $\chi^2$ looks like a sum of squared standardized variables.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the $\chi^2$ test about multinomial probabilities $H_0: \pi_j = \pi_{j0}, j = 1, \ldots, c$ where $\sum_j \pi_{j0} = 1$, it can be shown that Pearson $\chi^2$ test statistic is identical to the famous [score test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_test) statistic, whose intuition should be very clear to statistics-major students (i.e., testing the slope of log-likelihood function).  To view it in another way, if the denominator of the test statistic were $m_i^2$ instead of $m_i$, then the test statistic would not converge in distribution to the desired $\chi^2_{c - 1}$ asymptotic distribution.

For more details and mathematical proofs of the above claim, I refer you to read Section 1.3.3, Section 1.5.2 and Section 1.5.4 of *Categorical Data Analysis* (2nd edition) by Alan Agresti.

---

Per @Sextus Empiricus's request, I am adding a proof to the equivalence of the Pearson's $\chi$-squared test and the score test (as a by-product, the proof also shows the equivalence of the Pearson's $\chi$-squared test and the Wald test) by myself below.  It was the solution to the exercise in the screenshot (see [this link](http://personal.psu.edu/drh20/asymp/lectures/) for a complete copy of the lecture notes where this exercise comes from):

[image]

In the proof below, $W_n$ and $R_n$ are notations for Wald statistic and score statistic respectively.

*Proof.* Since $\ell(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \sum_{j = 1}^k X_j\log p_j$ and $E[X_j] = np_j, j = 1, \ldots, k$
, it follows that
\begin{equation*}
    I(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{p_1} + \frac{1}{p_k} & \cdots & \frac{1}{p_k} \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \frac{1}{p_k} & \cdots & \frac{1}{p_{k - 1}} + \frac{1}{p_k} 
    \end{pmatrix} = 
    \Lambda + \boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{1}^T/p_k,
\end{equation*}
where $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(p_1^{-1}, \ldots, p_{k - 1}^{-1}), \boldsymbol{1} = (1, \ldots, 1)^T \in 
\mathbb{R}^{k - 1}$. Furthermore, if denoting $(X_1, \ldots, X_{k - 1})^T$ by $\boldsymbol{X}$, then
\begin{equation*}
    \nabla \ell(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{X_1}{p_1} - \frac{X_k}{p_k} & \cdots & \frac{X_{k - 1}}{p_{k - 1}} - \frac{X_k}{p_k}
    \end{pmatrix}^T = \Lambda\boldsymbol{X} - \frac{X_k}{p_k}\boldsymbol{1}.
\end{equation*}
We first show that $W_n = \chi^2 \equiv \sum_{j = 1}^k \frac{(X_j - np_j)^2}{np_j}$. It
follows by $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n = \boldsymbol{X}/n$ that
\begin{align*}
    & W_n = n(\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n - \boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^TI(\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)(\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_n - \boldsymbol{\theta}^0) \\
    = & \frac{1}{n}(\boldsymbol{X} - n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^T(\Lambda + \boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{1}^T/p_k)(\boldsymbol{X} - 
    n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^T \\
    = & \frac{1}{n}(\boldsymbol{X} - n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^T\Lambda(\boldsymbol{X} - n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^T + 
    \frac{1}{np_k}(\boldsymbol{X} - n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^T\boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{1}^T(\boldsymbol{X} - n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^T \\
    = & \sum_{j = 1}^{k - 1}\frac{(X_j - np_j)^2}{np_j} + \frac{(X_k - np_k)^2}{np_k} \\
    = & \sum_{j = 1}^k\frac{(X_j - np_j)^2}{np_j} = \chi^2.
\end{align*}

We next show that $R_n = \chi^2$, for which we need to evaluate $I(\boldsymbol{\theta})^{-1}$ first.
By [Sherman-Morrison-Woodburry formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) $(A + UV)^{-1} = 
A^{-1} - A^{-1}U(I + VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}$,
\begin{align*}
    & I(\boldsymbol{\theta})^{-1} = p_k(p_k\Lambda + \boldsymbol{1}\boldsymbol{1}^T)^{-1} \\
  = & p_k\left[p_k^{-1}\Lambda^{-1} - p_k^{-1}\Lambda^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}\left(1 + \boldsymbol{1}^Tp_k^{-1}\Lambda^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}\right)^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}^Tp_k^{-1}\Lambda^{-1}\right] \\
  = & \operatorname{diag}(p_1, \ldots, p_{k - 1}) - (p_1, \ldots, p_{k - 1})^T\left(1 + \sum_{j = 1}^{k - 1}\frac{p_j}{p_k}\right)^{-1}(p_1, \ldots, p_{k - 1})/p_k \\
  = & \Lambda^{-1} - \boldsymbol{\theta}\boldsymbol{\theta}^T, 
\end{align*}
Noting that $\boldsymbol{1}^T\Lambda^{-1} = \boldsymbol{\theta}^{0T}$, $\Lambda\theta = \boldsymbol{1}$, $\boldsymbol{\theta}^{0T}\boldsymbol{1} = 1 - p_k$, $\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{1} = n - X_k$, we have
\begin{align*}
    & R_n = \frac{1}{n}\nabla \ell(\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^T I^{-1}(\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)\nabla 
    \ell(\boldsymbol{\theta}^0) \\
  = & \frac{1}{n}\left(\Lambda\boldsymbol{X} - \frac{X_k}{p_k}\boldsymbol{1}\right)^T(\Lambda^{-1} - \boldsymbol{\theta}^0\boldsymbol{\theta}^{0T})\left(\Lambda\boldsymbol{X} - \frac{X_k}{p_k}\boldsymbol{1}\right) \\
  = & \frac{1}{n}(\boldsymbol{X} - n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)\left(\Lambda\boldsymbol{X} - \Lambda n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0 + \Lambda n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0 - \frac{X_k}{p_k}\boldsymbol{1}\right) \\
  = & \frac{1}{n}(\boldsymbol{X} - n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^{T}\Lambda(\boldsymbol{X} - n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0) + (\boldsymbol{X} - n\boldsymbol{\theta}^0)^T\frac{np_k - X_k}{np_k}\boldsymbol{1} \\
  = & \sum_{j = 1}^k \frac{(X_j - np_j)^2}{np_j} = \chi^2.
\end{align*}
In summary, $W_n = R_n = \chi^2$.

Comment: Do you have a more direct reference or derivation that shows that the $\chi^2$ statistic is equal to statistic used in the score test?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Sure.  I realized it might be easier to address your request by just pasting a proof by myself dug out from my old school work :).

Answer (score 2):

Every equation has many equivalent forms. The trick here is to choose a form that supports the most intuitive understanding for *you*. For *me*, the most intuitive form is not Pearson's classic equation (although it is undoubtedly the most elegant), but an equivalent form that includes a different mix of terms:
$$
\begin{align}
\chi^2 &=  \sum \frac{\left(x_{i}-m_{i}\right)}{m_{i}}^2
\\
&= \sum \frac{\left(x_{i}-np_{i}\right)}{np{i}}^2
\\
&= \sum \frac{\left(x_{i}-np_{i}\right)}{np{i}\left(1-p_{i}\right)}^2\left(1-p_{i}\right)
\\
&= \sum Z_{i}^2\left(1-p_{i}\right)
\\
\end{align}
$$

Where $n$ = the sample size, $Z$ = a standardized observation, and $p$ = the probability associated with that observation. Now, it helps my understanding to consider that last arrangement as the starting point of our intuition in which case the new question becomes: "why do we multiply $Z_{i}^2$ by $\left(1-p_{i}\right)$?".

To answer this, consider a multinomial distribution with three variables. We can plot this distribution on a 3D scatter where each axis represents $Z_{i}$. Here, all the data resides perfectly on a 2D plane, and the contours of the distribution are often elliptical (when looking at the 2D plane from directly above):

[image]

Now, if we multiply the values along each axis by $\sqrt{\left(1-p_{i}\right)}$ (represented by $T_{i}$ in the chart below) then it has the effect of transforming the elliptical distribution into a circular distribution:

[image]

Moreover, this distribution is standardized in that its two principal component axes (not shown) represent independent standard normal variables (and from this we can construct the chi-square distribution for k=2).

So, what Pearson discovered in his chi-square equation was a "recipe" for transforming the original axes such that the resulting distribution is circular in shape (spherical in higher dimensions), and standardized. And it just so happens that $Z_{i}^2\left(1-p_{i}\right)$ reduces to the classic form posted in your question.

I too have been curious about the intuition behind the test and I've captured some insights in [this post](https://medium.com/@rezwan.islam99/demystifying-the-chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test-c3347718b877).

Comment: This post is difficult to follow because it starts by discussing undefined quantities $Z_i$ and $p_i,$ only implicitly relating them to the original equation in the final sequence of formulas.  It reads like you jumped into the middle of an explanation.  Would you consider starting at the beginning with an explanation of what these terms are and why they arise?

Comment: Sure, I've just updated to improve the flow.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, some key parts of this are incorrect.  Consider the case where all $p_i$ are equal.  You appear to conclude then that $\chi^2$ is a *multiple* of a sum of independent squared standardized variables: but that would cause you to conclude the degrees of freedom are greater than what they really are and the multiplier is incorrect.

Comment: The equation I have stated (unless I possibly made a typo somewhere?) is a simple rearrangement of Pearson's $\chi^2$ equation, i.e. it is equivalent. I'm not concluding that $\chi^2$ is a multiple of a sum of *independent* squared standardized variables; the $Z_{i}$ terms are *dependent*. But the equation does yield the sum of two *independent* standard normal variables, which represents the correct number of degrees of freedom.

Comment: This toy example may help to fill-in any gaps in my last comment. Consider rolling a 3 sided die 90 times and seeing 30 counts of face 1, 27 of 2 and 33 of 3. In R we can write `chisq.test(x=c(30,27,33), p=c(1/3,1/3,1/3))$statistic` to get $\chi^2$
=0.6. And what I'm suggesting is: `# Z = (O-E)^2/(n*p*(1-p))
Z1 <- (30-30)^2/(90*1/3*2/3); 
Z2 <- (27-30)^2/(90*1/3*2/3);
Z3 <- (33-30)^2/(90*1/3*2/3);

(1-1/3) * Z1 + (1-1/3) * Z2 + (1-1/3) * Z3` ...which also yields 0.6.

Answer (score 0):

We are dealing with counts. If the probability to encounter the outcome $i$ is $p_i$, then the distribution of the measured counts is Poisson with parameter $\lambda=p_in$ where $n$ is total number of trials. As you know the variance of Poisson is also $\lambda$, that's why you get the sum of standard normals $(x_i-\mu_i)^2/\sigma_i^2=(x_i-\mu_i)^2/\mu_i$

Comment: But these terms are neither normal nor independent!