# chi squared test, motivation for formula for statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I am learning about chi squared tests, specifically about test for independence and goodness of fit test. In both tests statistic is sum of square of differences between observed and expected data divided by expected data.

Why we use exactly this statistic in this test, why don't we use some other formulas?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478121/20519

Comment: Other statistics can be used, and indeed some are used. The one you're learning about is the most commonly used.